# dlopen failing on Rhel 7.2, 64 bit for libjvm.so

Tags: c++, dlopen, rhel7

I am calling dlopen `("libjvm.so", RTLD_NOLOAD)` on RHEL 64 within a  64 bit java process.  and it fails with error:

```
 libjvm.so: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument
```

I did `lsof -p <pid of java process>` and it shows libjvm.so as a loaded module. the libjvm.so is loaded from  path `jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so`.
Not able to find more about that error . The same thing works fine when using  32 bit version of java. where the  libjvm.so is being loaded from `lib/i386/client`  directory. Appreciate any pointers about where to look for the reason or what this error really means. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `invalid mode for dlopen()`

This is correct error: you've called `dlopen` with invalid mode.

From [dlopen man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

```
One of the following two values must be included in flags:
   RTLD_LAZY ...
   RTLD_NOW  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .  Let me give it a shot .. but the same thing works fine when  using 32 bit  Java process.. . I don't want to load that library .. i just want to get handle to the one that is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the response .. RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_NOLOAD is working .. I don't know why this should be required for 64x .. on 32 it works with just RTLD_NOLOAD..

Comment: I just checked GLIBC sources, and the check for "one of `RTLD_{NOW,LAZY}` must be set" was added in 1998. I have no explanation of why this works for you in 32-bit mode; it shouldn't. A trivial test on my system trying to `dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_NOLOAD)` fails in both 32 and 64-bit modes.

Comment: Thanks @Employed Russian. I appreciate your help.